# laravel 4: How to log a user in without username and password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently integrating my laravel app into a wordpress site and would like to authenticate of the wordpress user table.

I successfully matching the hashes via using the script phpasa http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

And my app currently uses this method to login:

```
Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password')));
```

How can i set a logged in session for the user without passing and email and password parameter?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly:

Find your use whatever way you can:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

And tell Laravel to log him in directly:

```
Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just one more question: The user table im using isn't useing standard column names.. does that matter for this to work?

Comment: @TheNickyYo `Auth::loginUsingId($id);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, i have found what i was looking for, if my apps login hashed pass matches that of the wordpress user table then ill just give a basic login. Auth::onceBasic();

Comment: @Santa, internally `Auth::loginUsingId()` uses `Auth::login()`, so it's pretty much the same.